# Many decimal places required in python calculations

Tags: python, sum, decimal

I need to accurately sum up a long list of decimal numbers with a precision of at least 50 decimal places. I also need to be able to print some sums. What I really need is unlimited decimal places.

I have no good idea about how to do this. Floating numbers are supposed to be converted to strings and then printed out with the Decimal module right? But I have no success in understanding the module or its limitations. If someone could help me with this problem and/or maybe hint me of some instructive article about the decimal module or floating point numbers in python, it would really help me and others.

My attempt was:

```
from __future__ import division
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 160

summan = 0
lista = [1/4,1/3,1/5,1/6,1/7,1/9,1/10,1/11]

for x in lista:
    summan += x
    print Decimal(str(summan))
```

Comment: Please provide some code and context for what isn't succeeding and what you don't understand.

Comment: The python docs are a good place to start [decimal — Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). Read about contexts and especially look at `decimal.getcontext().prec=50` which will set the default precision for your program.

Comment: Surely the docs are the 'instructive article' you're looking for.  They have plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [at the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)... for fraction divisions with high precision you can do something like:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 160

summan = 0
lista = ['1/4','1/3','1/5','1/6','1/7','1/9','1/10','1/11']

for x in lista:
    den, num = x.split('/')
    print Decimal(den) / Decimal(num)
```

Comment: I hope it worked for you... if you think the answer fit your needs you can even accept it clicking in the arrow at the left-hand side...

Comment: Well it did not really help yet, but I think that is because of my ignorance. Do I need to conver,t let us say, "1/4" to a str(floating_point_number_of_1/4) ?

Comment: In Python 2.x if you do `1/4` it will do a floor division, resulting in `0`, so you have to do `1./4` or `1/4.`, to tell Python these are floating points (see the `.`)... and then it should work...

Comment: AHA! So the from __future__ import division is not enough? Well anyway, your solution doesn´t seem to fit 2.6, it gives me: File "C:\Python26\lib\decimal.py", line 3680, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '1./4'

Comment: SORRY... it is enough... I haven't paid enough attention, I did not see in your question... don't worry with the floor division in this case...

Comment: This error is because you are passing a string... try to pass: `Decimal(float('1/4.'))` and you will not get this error...

Comment: BUt you HAVE TO pass it as a string, or so it says. And how can I get map( Decimal, old_list_with_strings_maybe ) with the float option?

Comment: Haha! So simple! But plz tell me what den, means? How does it recognize it?